# Display showing weird but only on wallpapers, right click menu, and app drawer

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display

I don't know what can be the cause, if an hardware or software issue, everything looks fine.

I also noticed some weird visual glitches, like when I select a piece of text, it blinks one time very fast, then it's ok.

Here a couple of screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DquIn.jpg  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKYTu.jpg

Comment: The graphics is probably about to fail.

Comment: I have the same though, perhaps it's the time for me to get a new laptop.

Comment: Yes, make sure you have BACKUPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop have an hardware issue. I got a new one.